# Rails 4.2 belongs_to relation and before_create callback not setting model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a class `Client` that `belongs_to` another class `Account`

`Account` deals only with authenticating an account and dishing out an API key and there are many types of users that could have an account. I have a `before_create` callback that creates an `Account` when `Client` has it's `create` method called. Both the `Client` and `Account` instances get created (or not) appropriately but the `account_id` column is not getting set.

Relevant code follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, ->{includes :api_key}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
  before_create :generate_account

  private

  def generate_account
    self.account = Account.create(password: :password, password_confirmation: :confirm_password)
  end
end
```

In the rails console I run `Client.create("email"=>"XXXXXXX", "account_attributes"=>{"password"=>"password","password_confirmation"=>"password"})`

And the output is as follows:

```
(24.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (29.4ms)  INSERT INTO `accounts` (`password_digest`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('XXXXXXXXXX', '2015-04-13 17:50:36', '2015-04-13 17:50:36')
  Client Exists (29.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`account_id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  SQL (32.1ms)  INSERT INTO `clients` (`email`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('XXXXXXX', '2015-04-13 17:50:36', '2015-04-13 17:50:36')
   (42.0ms)  COMMIT
```

And the console outputs this as it's response: `#<Client id: 6, email: "XXXXXXXXX", account_id: nil, created_at: "2015-04-13 17:50:36", updated_at: "2015-04-13 17:50:36">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client model's `accepts_nested_attributes_for` setting should handle the account creation and relationship setting automatically for you.  Try taking out the `generate_account` callback and see if that helps.

Comment: It worked! Ha! Rails' magic sauce is taking a while to get used to, thanks for the help.